# Labialisation and palatisation in IPA: one consonant or two phones?

Tags: phonology, ipa, phonemes

When is a consonant simply followed by labliasing sound like /u/ or /w/ and when is the consonant itself considered palatised or labialised?

For instance, French *point*, in IPA, /pwɛ̃/ and Croatian *pjevati* /pjêʋati/. Contrast this with Polish *śpiewać* which may have IPA /ɕpʲɛvat͡ɕ/ or /ɕpjɛvat͡ɕ/ or English *swoon* may have IPA /sʷuːn/ or /swuːn/ but usually the latter.

The answer, I would guess, is when the phonemic difference is contrastive. This is problematic because in many phonetic transcriptions of words which do mark consonants with a raised modifier (see Polish and English above), the sounds are not contrastive in the language described.

```
/pʲ/ and /pj/
/sʷ/ and /sw/
```

If these are not interchangeable, when should I use either?

Comment: What are you asking, sorry?

Comment: First sentence.

Comment: This does cause problems sometimes, but usually only in languages where both occur and contrast. Historically, the reconstruction of PIE *_ekwos_ (instead of *_ekʷos_) is an example of the problem. In Lushootseed, which has both velar and labiovelar stops, and also velar stop plus /w/ clusters, one way to detect the labiovelars is to notice whether the consonant itself is rounded by listening for diphthongization of preceding vowels. Thus /-akʷ/ will be pronounced [aʊkʷ], because the [k] part is rounded.

Comment: @slipperyiron are you asking how to understand it based on IPA notation? If so, the following "j" in IPA means that the following consonant is /j/, while palatalization is never indicated this way. It is usually indicated either with superscript "j" or special character for the consonant or special character for the following vowel, depending or language.

Comment: What language is your last sentence referring to? "X and Y are separate sounds" is only meaningful in the context of a specific language. More generally, it's not clear to me which of the following two things you're asking: (a) how to distinguish between e.g. /pʲ/ and /pj/ in a language that contrasts the two, or (b) how to choose between the two notations in a language that doesn't contrast them.

Comment: @Anixx I want to know which to choose and **why**. The application is that I'm trying to ascertain sound changes in the Nilotic Luo languages. I haven't got primary data for reference, I working from phonetic orthography -> IPA. Eg. reflexes of /*kjɛ̀l/ are /-cɛl/ /-cɪel/ /cjɛɛl/ /-cɪɛ̀l/ /-kjɛ̀l/. I think the last may in fact be a /-kʲɛ̀l/. There's also a /pw/~/pʷ/ allophone to deal with.

Comment: @TKR I want to know how to choose in a language that doesn't contrast them. So are /sʷuːn/ or /swuːn/ interchangeable transcriptions or allophones?

Comment: @slipperyiron I can tell you that when I read professional linguistic literature, I usually face with ad-hoc transcription systems, without any proper description. The professional comparative linguists even when dealing with Russian that contrasts the two, often use "j" where there is no such sound! For instance, I often see things like "bjelo" when dealing with Russian, even though this field requires precision in depiction of phonemes!

Comment: For W. Nilotic, diphthongization alternations favor a cluster analysis. Usually the palatal is written as *c*: it varies between IPA c, tʃ, tç and similar sounds. You don't get coda C+glide, but you do get coda palatals. But palatals are thought to be different from palatalized velars.

Comment: @Anixx Can you be more specific? What "professional comparative linguists" did you have in mind? And what exactly is bjelo?

Comment: @Alex B. see my answer.

Comment: @Anixx I saw your answer - the questions I asked you above are not addressed there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deciding between a cluster analysis and a coarticulation analysis when the two do not phonemically contrast is always to some extent a matter of analytical choice, so there's no general answer to your question. Even in English [at least one serious linguist](http://wa.amu.edu.pl/wa/Gasiorowski_Piotr) has proposed that e.g. the initial cluster of a word like *stop* should be considered a single phoneme. Here are some possible factors that could influence your choice:

- Does [j] occur outside of these sequences? If not, it's unlikely to be a separate phoneme.
- Does your language generally allow initial clusters? If not, this is a point in favor of the palatalization analysis.
- Is there evidence for a syllable boundary between (for example) the [p] and the [j]? If so, this points to the cluster analysis.
- Can your sound occur in coda? If so, the sonority hierarchy would suggest it's a single phoneme.
- In languages with distinctive palatalization, this generally affects whole series of consonants (e.g. all the velars, or even all the stops): is this true in your language?
- How frequent are the sounds/sequences in question? If they're single phonemes, you should expect their frequency to be roughly comparable with that of other phonemes; if they're clusters, they're likely to be significantly less common than most phonemes.

Comment: This an excellent guide. Better than anything I would have hoped for. Thank you. For Anuak, Mabaan and Shilluk, this breaks 4:1 in favour of palatalization analysis. Palatalised sounds don't occur in coda in the la

Comment: Multiple serious linguists have proposed the single-phoneme analysis for all onset clusters in English: Osamu Fujimura's C-D model features this as a means of disposing of linear order of segments.

Comment: @user6726 Thanks, I didn't know that. It seems that if you treat all clusters as phonemes then you've just redefined "phoneme" as "allowed cluster" -- what's the theoretical payoff there?

Comment: @TKR, disappointingly minimal. You don't have to say what order phonemes come in: it follows from prosodic structure. I'm not a huge fan, I have to say, but we just *love* exploiting "predictable" properties.

Answer (score -2):

IPA was not designed for languages with palatalized consonants, so it uses different signs when dealing with different languages. For instance, in Russian, Irish and German the IPA notation is different. In Russian and Irish it is mostly denoted by the IPA on the consonant, in German - with the following vowel. Even for Russian some palatalized consonants get superscript j as indication of palatalization, while others have separate characters, in some cases the both ways are permitted. IPA is just a mess.

If you are asking how to understand it based on IPA notation, the following "j" in IPA means that the following consonant is /j/, while palatalization should never be indicated this way. It is usually indicated either with superscript "j" or special character for the consonant or special character for the following vowel, depending on language.

Comment: What dialect of German has palatalized consonants?

Comment: @TKR everyone, in words such as München (which has two palatalized consonants) https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cc/De-M%C3%BCnchen.ogg The consonant denoted as "ch" in German as well as "j" are always palatalized. Moreover, even English has palatalized consonants, but IPA does not indicate them in English.

Comment: OK, but there's no phonological contrast there -- it's a different beast from the Russian or Irish type of situation, where palatalization is contrastive. Transcribing non-contrastive elements is always a matter of choice to some degree. Anyway I don't see how "IPA is a mess" -- the [ʲ] symbol is perfectly clear.

Comment: @TKR there IS contrast, but when IPA describes German, it changes the symbol for a vowel. If the same in Russian, it adds a superscript to a consonant. "[ʲ] symbol is perfectly clear." - it is used in IPA only for a part of consonants. For others it does not. For instance, the consonant [j] is palatalized and has a special symbol in IPA (not superscript). Many other consonants as well have special symbol for a palatalized version.

Comment: The contrast in German is in the vowels, not the consonants -- at least, that's the standard analysis. If your analysis places it on the consonants, IPA gives you the same tools to express that for German as it does for Russian.

Comment: @TKR The both the vowel and consonant differ. Both in Russian and German. One can say the contrast is in the junction. In German the words can start from such vowels and the palatalized consonants are not contrasted at the word-end. In Russian, the opposite, the vowels do not contrast in the word-beginning (except и and ы) but the consonants contrast at the word-end. This is the basis for different phoneme analysis. But IPA is not about phonemes as it claimed.

Comment: Both the vowel and the consonant may differ phonetically, but the IPA represents the standard theoretical assumption that the phonological contrast is on one of the two, not both.

Comment: @TKR that's why it is bad to represent phones and why it represents the same sounds of different languages differently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49868/discussion-between-tkr-and-anixx).

Answer (score -3):

> The application is that I'm trying to ascertain sound changes in the
>   Nilotic Luo languages

I can tell you that when I read professional linguistic literature, I usually face with ad-hoc transcription systems, without any proper description. The professional comparative linguists even when dealing with Russian that contrasts the two, often use "j" where there is no such sound! For instance, I often see things like "bjelo" when dealing with Russian, even though this field requires precision in depiction of phonemes!

Below is an excerpt from Fortson's "Indo-European language and culture". All listed words are supposed to be Russian and used to analyze sound changes:

[image]

But what??? How does he indicate palatalization? In multiple different ways!
At the end of the words he uses apostrophe, except the word *kakoj* where he does not indicate it at all. In the middle of the words he either uses "j" in words that do **not** have this sound (*knjaz'*, *desjat'*) or simply does not indicate palatalization at all (*čtenie* has all 3 consonants palatalized, but it is not indicated by Fortson, *dennica* has 2 palatalized consonants, d and n). In word *desjat'* all 3 consonants are palatalized, but Fortson does not indicate palatalization at all in the first case, uses "j" in the second case and apostrophe in the third case. Three different methods in one word!

How one can arrive at precise reconstruction of an ancient language if he does not distinguish different consonants in a living, widespread language, where these differences are phonemic and etymologically determined?!

Comment: The reconstruction isn't really meant to inform genetic classification—yet. Nilotic subclassification is very stable. The comparative method under neogrammarian assumptions can be applied to quickly identify likely errors so that we know what forms require new corroborating evidence. This is especially important for poorly attested spoken languages which don't yet have an orthography. Most fieldwork is done near blind which brings a sizeable risk of error. This is the intended use of my work.

Comment: Downvoted because this doesn't address the question.

Comment: I assume the palatalization is not marked in "čtenie" because it's predictable: č is always palatalized, consonants before e in native Russian words are always palatalized, and consonants before i are always palatalized.

Comment: @TKR the question is, as understood it, how to convert some ad-hoc transliteration system to IPA.

Comment: @sumelic where these rules come from? This is completely ad-hoc writing system, and if it presupposes knowledge of Russian, why he does not use Russian letters? Also, the question was about ʲ vs j and we can see that Fortson uses j wildly to both indicate palatalization AND to indicate a consonant [j].

Comment: The question isn't really about transcription but about analysis: how do you distinguish between a single coarticulated phoneme and a sequence of two phonemes? But even if it was about IPA, this answer has nothing to do with IPA.